# restrict creation of of objects to a factory in swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, design-patterns, factory-pattern, swift4.2

I have a family of classes in swift 4.2 and I want to restrict the creation of those instances only to the factory class, in C++ I can enforce this by declaring the constructors as private and add the friend keyword to the factory method like this:

```
class A{
 friend factoryClass::createInstance(int type);
  private A();
}

class subA: private A{
  friend factoryClass::createInstance(int type);
  private subA() : A(){
  }
}

class factoryClass{
    static A* createInstance(int type){
      switch(type){
      case 0:
         return new A();
      case 1:
      default:
         return new subA();
      }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in swift 4.2? I'm pretty a new on this.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible with `fileprivate` keyword.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

```swift
class A {
    fileprivate init() {

    }
}

class SubA: A {
    fileprivate override init() {

    }
}

class FactoryClass {
    static func createInstance(type: Int) -> A {
        switch type {
        case 0:
            return A()
        default:
            return SubA()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But does this means that all of my class family have to be declared and implemented in the same file?